# Can't set default useState to incoming redux data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to set state with the default value from a redux reducer. I can console.log the value just fine, I'm guessing its not "fast" enough?

I tried setting a variable to the reducer value I need then calling useState with the variable but that didnt work either...

```
const ChatProvider = ({ children }) => {
  
  const conversations = useSelector((state) => state.conversations) // all conversations

  
  const [activeConversationId, setActiveConversationId] = useState(conversations[1]?.conversationSid)
  console.log(conversations[1]?.conversationSid) // I get my string "Ox990"
  console.log(activeConversationId) // I get undefined...

// render stuff here

}
```

Comment: How many times are you seeing your `console.log` statements (e.g., is `ChatProvider` re-rendering)? And how do the reducer(s) that are responsible for setting `state.conversations` work?

Comment: `useState` is a mess; it's not strictly pure (it has side effect of storing the value on first call), while all other hooks (such as `useSelectors`) assume the component is pure, and hence might return values that aren't meant to be processed by side-effectful code. What you could do is `useEffect(() => setActiveConversationId(....))`, which will be called only with correct closures. But that's probably not satisfactory.

Comment: I'd try to put the first conversation ID in a `const firstConversationId = useMemo(() => conversations[1]?.conversationSid, [conversations]);` to pin the value down. Then use `firstConversationId` to initialize the state of `activeConversationId`.